# Google apps directory sync to map google users to LDAP

Tags: active-directory, google-api, ldap, google-apps

Can I use GADS to import google apps user accounts to a blank ldap server? I see GADS can be used to sync from google apps to existing users in ldap server. I do not have an existing LDAP account. I want to create a new LDAP server and map the users from google apps to the ldap server and get all the updates(not just one time). Can GADS do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  GADS is a one-way sync from LDAP to Google Apps.  It has no capability to write to LDAP.